# How to join with a table when there are nested values in sql?

Tags: postgresql

Assume a table t1 and t2 as follows:

```
t1_profile_id | nested_t2_ids
--------------|--------------
            1 |       15 | 16
            2 |             3
            3 |          NULL
```

```
t2_id |      name
------|----------
   15 |    Helena
   16 |     Chris
    3 |       Jim
```

and my goal is to pull the data in the following format:

```
profile_id | t2_ids |    name
-----------|--------|--------
         1 |     15 |  Helena
         1 |     16 |   Chris
         2 |      3 |     Jim
```

I can bring the first two desired columns by the following query:

```
select t1.t1_profile_id , unnest(string_to_array(t1.nested_t2_ids, ' | ')) as t2_ids
from t1
```

but I am confused how to join with t2 table.

Some help please?

Comment: I'm unsure about the particulars of your dataset, but this approach doesn't seem to be well-normalized data, i.e., violates the First Normal Form principle. As long as you aren't too deep into the project, I would suggest separating that nested multiple entry into entries, i.e. `1`, `15`, and `1`,`16`.

Comment: Nested values, that's something you should really avoid in a relational database. Is is possible, but you keep on shooting yourself in the foot. Your next question will be `why is my query so slow?` or `how to avoid inconsistencies in my data?`. Advise: Normalize your data to 3NF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are half-way there. Now that you have unnested data, you want to toss the SQL that produces that unnested result-set into a subquery, and then join:

```
SELECT table1.t1_profile_id, t1.t2_ids, t2.name
FROM 
   (
     select 
       t1_profile_id, 
       unnest(string_to_array(t1.nested_t2_ids, ' | ')) as t2_ids
     from t1
   ) AS table1 
   INNER JOIN t2 
      ON table1.t2_ids = t2.t2_id
```

That being said, please take the suggestions by folks in the comments into heavy consideration. Storing delimited data in a single column is a recipe for slow queries, bad data, and other disasters.